# How do I mount a Motorola Droid Bionic?

Tags: mount, android, usb-drive

I have 11.10 running on a virtual machine on my MacBook Pro.  I tried to connect my Motorola Droid Bionic via USB, but Ubuntu is not finding it (or I cannot find the mounted device).
I am new to Ubuntu, any help?
I am sure I am missing something easy.

Comment: What kind of virtual machine???

Comment: Type `lsusb` to see if it gets listed as detected.

Answer (score 1):

(if you are running VirtualBox)

When you plugin a device in to your computer running VirtualBox and you want the device to be detected by Ubuntu you need to click on ***Devices*** > ***USB Devices*** and select the device you have just plugged in. Check the list before and after plugging in the device and note the new addition(s) to the menu.

[image]

If you want a device to be available automatically when you plugin it in go to the Ubuntu guest settings, USB tab and add a filter to the list. Next time you plug it in it will be available automatically in Ubuntu.

[image]