# Windows7 in VirtualBox, does this mean I can use Windows software?

Tags: virtualbox

Now, my problem is that there are loads of things that I cannot use with wine.

Can I just install Windows7 in VirtualBox and use those few basic software (trade manager, Nokia 5800 PC Suite) that I really need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a VirtuaBox Windows system will allow you to run all the software that you would run inside a normal install (except for a lot of Direct3D software, ie, 3D games) and allow you to connect any USB accessory to the guest Windows system.

Of course that will cost you some performance but nothing too noticeable.

Any USB devices attached to the host can be seen in the guest via a USB 1.1 emulated controller included and if you install the closed source version (download directly from the VirtualBox site) you will emulate a USB 2.0 one.

---

To install VirtualBox you can do so via the software center or if you prefer you can install the closed source version from the Oracle's repos via these instructions

- [How do I install VirtualBox 4.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66765/how-to-install-virtualbox-4-1-4)

Mounting a USB device is simple and the instructions should be similar to the post bellow

- [How do I mount a Motorola Droid Bionic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89623/how-do-i-mount-a-motorola-droid-bionic/89627#89627)

Comment: Thanks for the info...I need to look into this USB emulation. :)

Comment: @Elysium added some links with info, have a look.

Comment: with guest additions, direct3d software should work fine too.

Comment: @H_7 agree, but not all of it, that was what I was trying to say.

Comment: Also see here for instructions on how to install the PUEL version with USB2.0 support: http://askubuntu.com/a/41487/3940